# How can I make gcc understand this template syntax?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, function

I'm trying to use a delegate library in gcc http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ImpossiblyFastCppDelegate.aspx but the "preferred syntax" is not recognized by gcc 4.3. I.e. howto make compiler understand the
template < RET_TYPE (ARG1, ARG2) > syntax instead of template ??

TIA
/Rob

Comment: RET_TYPE is presumably some macro. So #include the file that defines the macro. And are you really compiling with gcc? You should be using g++, for convenience if nothing else.

Comment: According to http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3267648/Preferred-syntax-on-Gplusplus-4-3-2-modified.aspx someone else had this problem. Do you need to use this code?

Comment: Yes, I do. Got it to work eventually with some help. And Neil, you're right I am using g++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a class has a template function as:

```
class A {
public:
    template<typename T>
    static void doThis() {...}
};

template<typename T>
class B {
public:
    static void doThat() {
       A::doThis<T>();
    }
};
```

then VC++ recognizes the syntax in class B, but for GCC you have to insert keyword **template**:

```
template<typename T>
class B {
public:
    static void doThat() {
       A::template doThis<T>();  // <-- "template" inserted
    }
};
```

and then it works in both GCC and VC++ (I wrote this off the top of my head, so I'm fairly sure its correct ;)